# "sort not a function" error in angularjs only in google chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, sorting

I ran into this problem and am unable to figure out why and couldn't find any explanation on google. I have a $http.get method to retrieve some data from a url, on success i am sorting the response. But when I run the page on google chrome, I get the error "TypeError: response.sort is not a function"

```
var orderOfGroups = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"];

$http.get(url)
.success( function (response, status, headers, config) {
    response.sort( function(a, b) {
        var aname = orderOfGroups.indexOf(a.team);
        var bname = orderOfGroups.indexOf(b.team);

        return bname-aname;
    });
});
```

I am getting the error at "response.sort" line. Also this is happening only in google chrome, I tested it in firefox and IE10, and its working fine on these browsers.
The json data I am receiving (response) has the following format

```
[
    {
        team: "gamma",
        value: "p"
    },
    {
        team: "alpha",
        value: "q"
    },
    ......
]
```

Could you please tell me how I can resolve this?

Comment: is `response` `array`? If not use `response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Is `response` ___always___ an `array`?

Comment: yes, response is always an array of objects. The object type also doesn't change.

Comment: `console.log(response instanceof Array)` is what?

Comment: it prints "false" in chrome and "true" in other browsers. "GET /TYPE=GETLIST HTTP/1.1" is being added at the beginning of the array and the entire array is converted into text in chrome. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `response` is not an Array. It could be an object with a property that contains the Array (e.g. `response.data`) or a string version of you array and then you will need to use `JSON.parse` and convert the string into an Array.

Anyway, [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is on Array's prototype - that means that all the arrays will have that property on them - This is **not** related to `AngularJS` or `google chrome`.

Comment: How is `$http.get` not related to AngularJS.

Comment: "TypeError: response.sort is not a function" - This is not related. $http.get doesn't return different values based on your browser.

Comment: Sure, that specific error isn't from Angular. But then we'd have to strip library tags off of all questions that are just about an error that occurs when using a library.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I'm not talking about the tags. I'm talking about how to solve this problem.

Comment: @akashrajkn - Add a console.log(response); and console.log(response instanceof Array) and paste the results.

Comment: Thanks, I found the source of error, In chrome for console.log(response), another extra line is being added "GET /TYPE=GETLIST HTTP/1.1" and the response is converted into 'text'. The same thing on other browsers, console.log(response), array of objects is printed and console.log(response instanceof Array) is "true".

Comment: why is the extra line being added in chrome? and is there any way to resolve it (other than manual parsing of the text)

Comment: That data should not be sent in the response...What server side framework\language are you using?

Comment: server side, perl is being used, but some other developer is taking care of that

Comment: Since this data appears in the response, I'm pretty sure the server returns it. Run a sniffer and check the servers exact response(in all browsers) and check weather it's a server issue or google chrome.